# Is it possible to have 2 sub-domains of the same IP with different routes on nginx?

Tags: nginx

Let's say I have mon.example.com and prom.example.com, both of them share the same IP.
Is it possible to route each of them to different services or content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, you can create two different server blocks and config your cases.

```
 server {
    server_name prom.example.com;
    access_log logs/domain1.access.log main;

    root /var/www/domain1.com/htdocs;
  }
```

for the other

```
 server {
    server_name mon.example.com;
    access_log  logs/domain2.access.log main;

    root /var/www/domain2.com/htdocs;
  }
```

Comment: Thanks! That was really helpful.
Can I use proxy_pass instead of root?

Comment: yes, you can, it depends on what do you want to do.